# Why is babel-loader not transforming object rest/spread?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I recently discovered in one of my projects that almost all of my JS code breaks in Edge 18 after the use of object rest/spread syntax. That was surprising to me as I expected that babel is transforming that into Edge compatible code but as I found out it does not. So went for *@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread* and added it to my webpack config and rerun webpack again. But with no luck. I used the debug option of babel to check if the plugin is actual used and the output says it does. But when I check the transpiled JS I still find the spread syntax in there completely untouched.

Babel debug output:

```
Using targets:
{
  "android": "4.4",
  "chrome": "74",
  "edge": "17",
  "firefox": "67",
  "ios": "10",
  "safari": "10"
}

Using modules transform: false

Using plugins:
  transform-template-literals { "android":"4.4", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  transform-literals { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-function-name { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  transform-arrow-functions { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-block-scoped-functions { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-classes { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-object-super { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-shorthand-properties { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-duplicate-keys { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-computed-properties { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-for-of { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-sticky-regex { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-dotall-regex { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "firefox":"67", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  transform-unicode-regex { "android":"4.4", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  transform-spread { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-parameters { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  transform-destructuring { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  transform-block-scoping { "android":"4.4", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  transform-new-target { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-regenerator { "android":"4.4" }
  transform-exponentiation-operator { "android":"4.4", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  transform-async-to-generator { "android":"4.4", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  proposal-async-generator-functions { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  proposal-object-rest-spread { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  proposal-unicode-property-regex { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "firefox":"67", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  proposal-json-strings { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  proposal-optional-catch-binding { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  transform-named-capturing-groups-regex { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "firefox":"67", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }

Using polyfills with `usage` option:

[/app/node_modules/swiper/dist/js/swiper.esm.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.array.concat { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.filter { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.find { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.includes { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.index-of { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.map { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.slice { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.sort { "android":"4.4", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  es.array.splice { "android":"4.4" }
  es.object.get-own-property-descriptor { "android":"4.4" }
  es.object.keys { "android":"4.4" }
  es.object.to-string { "android":"4.4" }
  es.parse-float { "android":"4.4" }
  es.parse-int { "android":"4.4" }
  es.regexp.to-string { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  es.string.includes { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  es.string.match { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  es.string.replace { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "firefox":"67", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  es.string.split { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  esnext.array.last-index { "android":"4.4", "chrome":"74", "edge":"17", "firefox":"67", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  web.dom-collections.for-each { "android":"4.4" }
 64% building 687/752 modules 65 active /app/node_modules/lodash-es/padStart.js
[/app/node_modules/dom7/dist/dom7.modular.js] Added following core-js polyfills:
  es.array.concat { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.filter { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.index-of { "android":"4.4" }
  es.array.splice { "android":"4.4" }
  es.object.assign { "android":"4.4" }
  es.object.keys { "android":"4.4" }
  es.parse-float { "android":"4.4" }
  es.string.match { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  es.string.replace { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17", "firefox":"67", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  es.string.split { "android":"4.4", "edge":"17" }
  es.string.trim { "android":"4.4", "ios":"10", "safari":"10" }
  web.dom-collections.for-each { "android":"4.4" }
Hash: b3541120009438066b1e
Version: webpack 4.30.0 / grunt-webpack 3.1.3
```

So since then I desperately try to get babel to transpile the code but nothing happens and I ran out of ideas and search terms to try. What makes it even more wierd is that the stack I used is nothing special and I used it already in other projects and never had that issue.

I'm using Vue, Webpack + Babel. Webpack is run via Grunt.

My webpack config:

```
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');

module.exports = function (grunt, options) {

    /* skip loading if task is not necessary for current target */
    if (!grunt.isConfigLoadingRequired('webpack')) {
        return {};
    }

    return (function () {

        const path = require('path');
        const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin;
        const DotenvPlugin = require('dotenv-webpack');
        const webpack = require('webpack');
        const plugins = [
            new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^(.*)$/, /node-jsb$/),
            new DotenvPlugin(),
            new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        ];

        /* remember to update jest transformer at tests/setup/ when changing loader options */
        const getLoaderRulesConfig = (targets, debug = false) => ([
            {
                test: /\.vue$/,
                loader: 'vue-loader',
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                enforce: 'pre',
                loader: 'import-glob',
                include: [path.resolve('<%= paths.src %>')],
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                /* remember to update jest transformIgnorePatterns at grunt/config/jest.js when adding includes */
                include: [
                    path.resolve('<%= paths.src %>'),
                    path.resolve('node_modules/dom7'),
                    path.resolve('node_modules/swiper'),
                ],
                options: {
                    compact: true,
                    cacheDirectory: true,
                    cacheCompression: false,
                    babelrc: false,
                    plugins: [
                        [
                            '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
                                regenerator: false,
                                useESModules: true,
                            },
                        ],
                        '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread',
                        ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
                    ],
                    presets: [
                        [
                            '@babel/preset-env', {
                                modules: false,
                                loose: true,
                                useBuiltIns: 'usage',
                                corejs: { version: 3, proposals: true },
                                targets,
                                debug,
                            },
                        ],
                    ],
                },
            },
        ]);

        return {
            options: {
                cache: true,
                entry: {
                    main: './<%= paths.src %>/js/_main.js',
                },
                output: {
                    filename: '[name].js',
                    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
                    path: path.resolve('<%= paths.static %>/generated/'),
                    publicPath: '/static/generated/',
                },
                plugins,
                resolve: {
                    mainFields: ['browser', 'main', 'module'],
                    symlinks: false,
                },
                performance: {
                    maxEntrypointSize: 500000,
                    maxAssetSize: 500000,
                },
            },
            analyze: {
                mode: 'production',
                watch: true,
                stats: {
                    maxModules: 99999,
                },
                optimization: {
                    concatenateModules: false,
                },
                output: {
                    path: path.resolve('<%= paths.tmp %>/js/'),
                },
                module: {
                    rules: getLoaderRulesConfig({ esmodules: true }, true),
                },
                plugins: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()],
            },
            dev: {
                mode: 'development',
                module: {
                    rules: getLoaderRulesConfig({ browsers: options.browserslist }, true),
                },
            },
            devModern: {
                mode: 'development',
                devtool: 'source-map',
                module: {
                    rules: getLoaderRulesConfig({ esmodules: true }),
                },
                output: {
                    filename: '[name].modern.js',
                    chunkFilename: '[name].modern.[chunkhash].js',
                },
            },
            dist: {
                mode: 'production',
                module: {
                    rules: getLoaderRulesConfig({ browsers: options.browserslist }),
                },
            },
            distModern: {
                mode: 'production',
                module: {
                    rules: getLoaderRulesConfig({ esmodules: true }),
                },
                output: {
                    filename: '[name].modern.js',
                    chunkFilename: '[name].modern.[chunkhash].js',
                },
            },
        };
    }());
};
```

I would love to hear your thoughts and I ideas what I maybe missed!

Comment: Can you clarify whether it is just your new project that has this problem? You start off making it sound like babel is completely broken for Edge 18 but then at the end you say " I used it already in other projects and never had that issue". What about those other projects? Do they have the issue now or are they still fine?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and sorry for the confusion. Its just that new project that has that issue. All the other ones are doing fine so far. I already checked their config but couldn't find any difference that would fix it. If that issue appeared their I would had some really exhausting working days ;-). And its not that babel is completely broken. Edge is just stumbling over that spread syntax and throwing that infamous SCRIPT 1028: Expected identifier, string or number error.

Answer (score 1):

The cause for me was, in the webpack config, only checking for js files e.g. `test: /\.js$/` as I only had js files in the codebase.

What I didn't realize is some of the node_modules were .mjs files, and were being ignored by babel completely.

The fix was to use `test: /\.m?js$/` in the webpack config to include .mjs files.